# MultivaluedMapImpl() with Jersey 2.9

Tags: java, eclipse, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to create key-value pair using `MultivaluedMap` (Jersey 2.9 in Eclipse) but somehow it is not able to find `MultivaluedMapImpl()`. What implementation of `MultivaluedMap` can  I use?

Thanks.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webtarget =client.target("http://localhost:8080").path("/usr/home/create/");


MultivaluedMap<String, String> queryParams = new MultivaluedMapImpl();
queryParams.add("xyz", abc);
```

Comment: Try `MultivaluedHashMap`? I think `MultivaluedMapImpl` is a RestEasy/Jersey-1 thing.

Comment: Thanks mabi. Tried MultivaluedHashMap earlier but then can't add parameters using 'queryParams.add'.

Comment: Huh? [The javadoc](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/AbstractMultivaluedMap.html) says you can.

Comment: For Jersey 2.0, queryParams can be defined while declaring WebTarget using ".queryParams". No need for MultivaluedMapImpl OR MultivaluedHashMap.

Comment: @Iosmx Using Jersey 2.30.1, I only see `WebTarget.queryParam()`, not `WebTarget.queryParams()`.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jaxrs-api/issues/408

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`MultivaluedStringMap`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-common/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/MultivaluedStringMap.java) class which extends `javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>`

Answer (score 2):

For Jersey 2.0, query parameters can be defined while declaring `WebTarget` using [WebTarget.html.queryParam(String, Object...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/WebTarget.html#queryParam(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

There seems to be no need for `MultivaluedMapImpl` or `MultivaluedHashMap`.

Comment: How is that useful if want to set a map with multiple parameters?